# How to reload the state after deleting an item in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

In my project on click of the delete button am calling one function and inside that am calling the api with delete method. After successfully deleting the Project from projectlist i am reloading the state. Here problem is, i am passing the project id in the URL. So after deleting the item the project id is still there in the url, because of why on state reload already deleted project id which is already there in the url is reloaded with no value inside it.

Below am giving the codes for better understanding of the code.

**survey.html**

```
   <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand" >
                <a>
                    Projects
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="obj in allProjects track by  $id(obj)">
                <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList({id: obj.ProjectID})" ng-click="getProjSurveys(obj.ProjectID)" ui-sref-active="activeProject" ng-init="getReloadProjSurveys()">{{obj.ProjectName}}<span class="projectsetting" ng-click="sendProjectID(obj.ProjectID)"><img src="./images/settings.png"/></span></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
       <div class="surveyContainer" ui-view></div>
```

**index.js (using UI routing)**

```
   .state('survey', {
        url: '/survey',
        views:{
            header:{
                templateUrl: 'common/headerTool.html',
                controller: 'headerController'
            },
            pageContent:{
                templateUrl: 'survey/survey.html',
                  controller: 'surveyController'
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/innerFooter.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }
    }).state('survey.surveyList', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'survey/surveyList.html',
        controller: ''
    });
```

**popup.html**
this is where am showing the delete confirmation popup

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteProject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this project</p>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><span type="button" class="cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span></div>
     <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 text-left"><span type="button" class="success" value="Delete" ng-click="projectDelete()" >Delete</span></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

On click on this button am calling `projectDelete()` which is inside this controller

**surveyController.js**

```
  $scope.sendProjectID = function(ProjectID){
     $scope.ProjectID = ProjectID;
   };
  $scope.projectDelete = function($event){
      $("#deleteProject").hide();
       UserService.DeleteProject($scope.ProjectID).then(
       function( data ) {
          console.log(data);
          state.reload();
         //$state.go('survey.surveyList',{id: 0});
         $("#deleteProject").modal("hide");
      });
   };
```

I tried with `state.reload()` and `$state.go('survey.surveyList',{id: 0});`. This $state.go() with id=0 is default one which i want to reload.

Comment: you only wanted to remove deleted record from list, right ?

Comment: How the `state` object is initialized ? for me, it should be : `$state.reload();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this  `$state.go('survey.surveyList',{id: 0}, {reload : true});` ?

reference : 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#toparams